# strtok_s crashes program when string is of char *

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, strtok

I am trying to get a token from a string that is delimited by space(" "). But the following code crashes the application when the string is of char * type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

char *str1 = "Hello World!"; //char str1[] works
char *token;
char *savePtr;

token = strtok_s(str1, " ", &savePtr);

printf("%s", token);

return 0;
}
```

I also get the following warnings:

```
C:\Users\Haris\Desktop\C files>gcc firstProgram.c -o firstprogram.exe
firstProgram.c: In function 'main':
firstProgram.c:10:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strtok_s' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 token = strtok_s(str1, " ", &savePtr);
         ^
firstProgram.c:10:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 token = strtok_s(str1, " ", &savePtr);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strtok_s` function modifies the thing the pointer points to, turning delimiters into zeroes. So it *cannot* take a pointer to a constant. But you pass it `str1`, which is a pointer to a string constant. When it tries to modify that string to turn the delimiters into zeroes, it tries to modify a constant. That is, of course, illegal.

Comment: Thank you. But then how can I use strtok_s to modify a string? What type should the string have?

Comment: *modify a string and get a token. For example the string I am working with is "echo par par". How can I use this function to get "echo"?

Comment: Just don't pass it a pointer to a constant. You can do this `char str1[]="hello world";` or like this `char *ptr=strdup("hello world");` or `char buf[80]; strcpy(buf, "hello world");` -- whatever. Just don't pass it a pointer to a constant.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense now.

Comment: Just curious, why is the string duplicate pointer from strdup modifiable but not the original pointer?

Comment: The original pointer is a pointer to a string constant. The other pointers are not. You can't modify a constant. You can modify pretty much anything else.